# Why does model gives me different result whenever I evaluate using device_map="auto"?

Tags: pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers

Currently I'm using 2 GPUs and running codes on [PyTorch docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/pytorch/pytorch). Tag is `pytorch:2.1.0-cuda12.1-cudnn8-runtime`.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 530.30.02              Driver Version: 530.30.02    CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090         On | 00000000:3B:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   86C    P2              263W / 420W|   6772MiB / 24576MiB |     72%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090         On | 00000000:5E:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 34%   64C    P2              207W / 420W|   2766MiB / 24576MiB |     19%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

As a simple practice, I have produced LoRA for RoBERTa using GLUE dataset.

Code is [almost same as official tutorial document](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter1/1), but result seems very wrong.

To make it simple, I'm using MRPC task only and wrote code like below.

```py
model = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("roberta-base", device_map = "auto", num_labels = 2)
# 'lora-mrpc' is local directory produced by fine-tuning.
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, "lora-mrpc", adapter_name = "lora-mrpc", device_map = "auto", num_labels = 2, local_files_only = True)

...

metric = evaluate.load("glue", task)

for batch in test_dataloader:
    batch = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()}

    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(**batch)

    logits = outputs.logits
    predictions = torch.argmax(logits, dim = -1)
    metric.add_batch(predictions = predictions, references = batch["labels"])

print(metric.compute())
```

By using `device_map="auto"`, results are:

```bash
$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do ./test.py; done;
{'accuracy': 0.5362318840579711, 'f1': 0.6941896024464832}
{'accuracy': 0.3344927536231884, 'f1': 0.003472222222222222}
{'accuracy': 0.5895652173913043, 'f1': 0.7404692082111436}
{'accuracy': 0.3779710144927536, 'f1': 0.14773629864972201}
{'accuracy': 0.664927536231884, 'f1': 0.7987465181058496}
{'accuracy': 0.664927536231884, 'f1': 0.7987465181058496}
{'accuracy': 0.664927536231884, 'f1': 0.7987465181058496}
{'accuracy': 0.35130434782608694, 'f1': 0.05089058524173028}
{'accuracy': 0.2608695652173913, 'f1': 0.39314612089481205}
{'accuracy': 0.664927536231884, 'f1': 0.7987465181058496}
```

But if I use `device_map=0`, then results are stable.

```bash
$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do ./test.py; done;
{'accuracy': 0.8417391304347827, 'f1': 0.8877005347593583}
{'accuracy': 0.8417391304347827, 'f1': 0.8877005347593583}
{'accuracy': 0.8417391304347827, 'f1': 0.8877005347593583}
{'accuracy': 0.8417391304347827, 'f1': 0.8877005347593583}
{'accuracy': 0.8417391304347827, 'f1': 0.8877005347593583}
{'accuracy': 0.8417391304347827, 'f1': 0.8877005347593583}
{'accuracy': 0.8417391304347827, 'f1': 0.8877005347593583}
{'accuracy': 0.8417391304347827, 'f1': 0.8877005347593583}
{'accuracy': 0.8417391304347827, 'f1': 0.8877005347593583}
{'accuracy': 0.8417391304347827, 'f1': 0.8877005347593583}
```

Also, I've used `device_map="auto"` when fine-tuning.

I have no idea what is going on...